# JMeter extracted value disappeared after the next sample

Tags: regex, jmeter

Hi:  Newbie to JMeter here.  I have been successful in using Regular Expression Extractor but my problem is the extracted value reverted to the default value after the next sample.  E.g., I successfully extracted the value to "Mytoken" from sample 1, this is proven by the Debug sampler as well as using it immediately in the next sample.  However, when I tried to reference "Mytoken" again a couple samples later, the value is replaced with my default value. How can I keep the value extracted to stay for the whole thread?

HT

Answer (score 1):

This is due to scoping, where do you put your extractor ?

see:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html
  paragraph 4.10 Scoping Rules

Put it as a child of sampler not after or before it.